# Upload user-specified local file to Google Cloud Storage via front-end

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have spent hours searching through Google docs and SO with no luck to my problem. I am creating a website that allows an authenticated user to load a fairly large (<10 GB) .csv file to Cloud Storage via a React front end. The file will then be loaded from Cloud Storage to Big Query.

Ideally, I would have liked to get the absolute path and then save this to a variable which I could then pass to upload_from_filename(). This code is in my Flask app which will act as an API.

The main issue is that due to the file size, I cannot load this file to my webserver and then up to GCS. I want to be able to load it directly from the user's machine. However, I have not been able to find a way around this due to the fact that I can only get the relative file name from the html elements.

The following is an extract of what I used to use on a non-web version which worked fine.

```
storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob(destination_blob_name) 
blob.upload_from_filename(path_to_source_file)
```

I must note that I am not using App Engine.

Is there any way to obtain the path via a web interface to be able to pass to the Google client API code which is on my Flask app?

Thanks.

Comment: You may want to look at the [`blob.upload_from_file(...)`](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.upload_from_file) method instead. It allows you to upload a file-like object, and you could wrap the `request.data` as a `StringIO` buffer or something to match. Alternatively you may want to look at [resumable media](https://googleapis.github.io/google-resumable-media-python/latest/google.resumable_media.requests.html) uploads.

Answer (score 0):

I would try Andrew's answer first.

If it does not work for you, try the [Blobstore Python API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/), which allows your application to serve data objects, Blobs, that are much larger than the size allowed for objects.

Just consider the following [limits](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/blobstore/#Python_Quotas_and_limits):

1. The maximum size of Blobstore data that can be read by the application with one API call is 32 megabytes.
2. The maximum number of files that can be uploaded in a single form POST is 500.